# Integrability of function in $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Just a quick question: consider the multiple integral$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{1}{(|x|^{2k}+1)^p}\,dx.
$$
What is the necessary condition on $(k,p)$ so that the previous integral is finite? Is $2kp>d$ enough?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes. $\phantom{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{{\bf{R}}^{d}}\dfrac{1}{(|x|^{2k}+1)^{p}}dx&=\omega_{n-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{r^{d-1}}{(r^{2k}+1)^{p}}dr\\
&\leq C\omega_{n-1}\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{r^{d-1}}{r^{2kp}}dr\\
&<\infty,
\end{align*}
if $2kp>d$.

Comment: What is $\omega_{n-1}$?

Comment: The surface area of the unit ball of ${\bf{R}}^{n}$.

Comment: It makes perfect sense. I'm really rusty on multivariable calculus. Thank you so much!